# Fetching part of a webpage with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I want to fetch a webpage, but the data I need is in the first fifteen characters. How can I only fetch part of the page, as opposed to the entire page, with `urllib`?

Comment: If you know where exactly the data is, you can try a range request (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021519/download-file-using-urllib-in-python-with-the-wget-c-feature) for details), given that their server supports that.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the `number of bytes to read` like this:

```
data = urllib.urlopen("www.example.com")
number_of_bytes_to_read = 15
content = data.read(number_of_bytes_to_read)
```

Comment: Err, the parameter for data.read() is a string and not an int?

Comment: @JonathanLingle: I know i just wrote that to describe the argument of `read()`